# Calculating the percentage of column value to all the column of a row with respective to max row value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table input table like Below

**Input Table**
[image: Input Table]

Need output like below

**OutPut Value**

[image: OutPut Value]

Can anyone help me to get the output in sql server 2008 R2 version

My requirement is for 1st row max row value is 584663 so for the 1st row all column value should be divided by 584663.
Same for 2nd row max row value is 782603 all column value for 2nd row should be divided by 782603. Output values are in percentage.

Comment: Don't add images. Add the data in the question itself

Comment: Thank You Standin.wolf for suggestion

Comment: your welcome.Its much more easier with text rather then images.

Comment: Yes sure , I am new to stack overflow i am trying to put create table script and insert script i am not able to . If you don't mind can i share the script through mail .

Comment: Put your script on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sql_variant` to get both data types in a single column:

```
select Category, case when Accessories = MaxVal then 100 else cast(Accessories*100.0/MaxVal as sql_variant) end Accessories
                , case when Active = MaxVal then 100 else cast(Active*100.0/MaxVal as sql_variant) end Active
                , case when Cosmetics = MaxVal then 100 else cast((Cosmetics*100.0/MaxVal) as sql_variant) end Cosmetics
                , case when Home = MaxVal then 100 else cast((Home*100.0/MaxVal) as sql_variant) end Home
                , case when [Infant Wear] = MaxVal then 100 else cast(([Infant Wear]*100.0/MaxVal) as sql_variant) end [Infant Wear]
from input_table
```

Please see the db<>fiddle demo [**here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=204e0be026825c0a5155d55b44a69e5a).